# XML to HTML function for Refreshing Information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

I am making a real time train board that pulls XML data from a website, populates it and animates it in. I have laid it out and got the animation set, but now I need help getting the XML data in the right spots.

Codepen of the animation: http://codepen.io/Spiderian/pen/FBjhk

The XML I'm trying to populate and recheck it every so often.

```
<trains>
<line><name>2</name><status>GOOD</status><text/><Date/><Time/></line>
<line><name>3</name><status>DELAYS</status><text/><Date/><Time/></line>
<line><name>4</name><status>WORK</status><text/><Date/><Time/></line>
<line><name>5</name><status>GOOD</status><text/><Date/><Time/></line>
</trains>
```

Will I have to use something different for the .append function to get it to work with the XML?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery will work fine with XML, too. I will focus on the parsing of it in this answer, since I assume you're already familiar with fetching the XML from whatever web service you use with AJAX.

Create a new jQuery object with the XML, and then use the typical selectors to parse it. For example, to  get the service on the first line, you can use the following:

```
var stats = xml.find('line:first status').text();
```

Here's how you can create a new jQuery object from XML:

```
var xml = $('<trains>\
<line><name>2</name><status>GOOD</status><text/><Date/><Time/></line>\
<line><name>3</name><status>DELAYS</status><text/><Date/><Time/></line>\
<line><name>4</name><status>WORK</status><text/><Date/><Time/></line>\
<line><name>5</name><status>GOOD</status><text/><Date/><Time/></line>\
</trains>');
```

Once you have the value from the XML, you can use either [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to add it to your existing markup.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/um250kuw/)

Comment: How would I get it to go in "$( '#slot09' ).append( '<div id="sn01a"><h1 class="bullet"><span class="tl123"><span class="bgw">-</span>2</span><span class="tl123"><span class="bgw">-</span>3</span></h1><div class="service"><h2>REPLACE THIS TEXT</h2></div></div>' );"

Comment: You could use the select `$('#slot09 h2').text('your text')`.